# Differences between Ubuntu and Ubuntu Gnome

Tags: unity, gnome

If I understand it right, than Ubuntu with Unity is the only "official" Ubuntu. But what exactly does this mean? Is it more stable, does it get updates faster than e.g. Ubuntu Gnome? Or is Ubuntu Gnome exactly the same, but with Gnome instead of Unity? Are there any advantages/disadvantages of installing normal Ubuntu and installing Gnome vs. installing Ubuntu Gnome?

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu derivatives you can check this link http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/flavours
The differences between Ubuntu and official derivatives are desktop environment and software it bundles by default, but it still the same Ubuntu. Unity is not somehow better but it is default on Ubuntu.

Using tasksel command you can try other derivatives and choose your favorite:

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
tasksel
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Gnome is officially supported. It is *exactly* the same, just Ubuntu Gnome has Gnome and Ubuntu has Unity. No real advantages or disadvantages - everything is subjective (i.e. You like one more).

P.S. Unity is based on Gnome.

Comment: Then why does Ubuntu have 5, but Ubuntu Gnome only 3 years support. Could I just install Ubuntu (with Unity) and gnome to get "Ubuntu Gnome" with 5 years of Support?

Comment: @Scott Yes, you can install Gnome (or any other DE, for that matter) and get full support.